# ListSelectionListener on JList not working

Tags: java, swing, jlist

i'm having problems with this listener, the gui in general constructs and works fine, also the jlist is there but when i select some items in the list i dont see the results and also not the printl() i wrote for test purpose, pls note this code is contained within the getJContentPane in order to add the event handler at init-time

```
private JList myList=new JList(dlm);//a defaultlistmodel 
myList.addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener() {
              public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent evt) {
                if (evt.getValueIsAdjusting()){
                    System.out.println("Eventhandler called");
                  return;
                }
                System.out.println("Eventhandler called");
                doMyMethod(evt);
              }
            });
```

The doMyMethod():

```
    private void doMyMethod(ListSelectionEvent e){

    if(e.getValueIsAdjusting()){


        return;

     }else{


         String item=(String)e.getSource();

         accounter.add(item);
     }

}
```

It is a very simple method which takes as parameter an instance of ListSelectionEvent 
The main problem in my opinion is not the doMyMethod() which performs very basic actions but the fact that the eventHandler is not fired at all, it seems lik the gui does not "listen" to this list at all

Any idea?

here the initialisation code:

```
   private JScrollPane getScrollBox() {
    if (scrollboxBox == null) {
        scrollboxBox = new JScrollPane();
        scrollBox.setBounds(new Rectangle(280, 56, 245, 204));
        scrollBox.getViewport().add(myList,null);

        myList.addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener() {

              public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent evt) {
                  System.out.println("addListSelectionListener");
                if (evt.getValueIsAdjusting()){
                    System.out.println("Eventhandler called");
                  return;
                }
                System.out.println("Eventhandler called");
                doMyMethod(evt);
              }
            });


    }
    return scrollboxBox;
}
```

Comment: What is with the attempt at recursion?

Comment: did not notice the recursive method, changed now:  synoniemenList.addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener() {
         public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent evt) {
           if (evt.getValueIsAdjusting()){
            System.out.println("Eventhandler called");
             return;
           }
           System.out.println("Eventhandler called");
           do(evt);
         }
       });

Comment: @JBoy, please edit your question with the new code.

Comment: @JBoy, could you also show all the initialization code for your `mylist` variable?

Comment: Not sure I understand the logic of your initialization code. If the content pane is null you add the listener to the list otherwise your don't add it. A proper SSCCE (http://sscce.org) would be more helpful.

Comment: @camickr, this simply means that if the pane is null, then initialize  it, i use visual editors for this, always worked properly, and indeed it still does, that listselectionlistener wont work in any part of the code

Comment: @camickr I guess the OP only put the relevant lines in `getJContentPane()`. I agree on having a proper SSCCE, rather than having information piece after piece.

Comment: @JBoy are you sure `mylist.addListSelectionListener(...)` is executed?

Comment: @camickr and jfpoilpret, thank you for you opinions, but this has nothing to do with the even listselectionlistener, again, that listenr would not work in any area of the entire code, the fact that its in the getJContentPane is just because i wanna make sure is there at app-start time

Comment: @JBoy then if you want some help, you will have to provide more (and also more relevant) details about: the code (an SSCCE is welcome!) and what you observe. The code that you show and the problem you describe doesn't show any problem, thus we would have to "infer" about what you don't tell us and guess what may happen...

Comment: @jfpoilpret not sure if its executed, the stack does not show it

Comment: ok i have now changed the code, i have placed the method listener-call in the  JScrollPane, the scrollPane is initialized without problems, the listener..its still not working

Comment: @JBoy now it even won't compile. You once used `scrollboxBox` and one line later `scrollBox` (unless you have defined both fields but then the code does not make sense). I once again suggest that you provide a SSCCE.

Comment: @JBoy please but without 'scrollBox.setBounds(new Rectangle(280, 56, 245, 204));'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After trying to understand what is going on in your question I understood that you are failing to get selected item in the list, when the selection is changed.

To present you how this could be achieved I have built the below example. You can observe there when each part of the if else is called. The `if(e.getValueIsAdjusting())` is execute always when you drag the moue over items. The else part is called when you release the mouse while previously clicked on an item.

There are some serious issues in the code that you have provided, therefore I tried to remove all that is unnecessary, e.g.

1.The `doMyMethod()` method and the `if(e.getValueIsAdjusting())` piece of code that is in it would never be called since you already are checking that condition before it is called. Plus there is no need to code a method working on listener's events, this code should stay inside the listener which is private. Then if you want to call programmatically its code you would call the listener.valueChanged(evt).

2.The `evt.getSource()` returns the object which is author of the event in this case the myList not the selected item which I think you were after, for this use the `getSelectedValue()` on the source or myList directly since this listener serves only this list.

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JList;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionListener;

public class ListTest extends JPanel
{
    private JScrollPane myScrollPane;
    private JList myList;
    private ListSelectionListener lSL = new ListSelectionListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent evt)
        {
            if(evt.getValueIsAdjusting())
            {
                System.out.println("Eventhandler called evt.getValueIsAdjusting() true");
                return;
            }
            else
            {
//              String item = (String) evt.getSource();//!!!Exception casting JList to String
                //maybe what you need is getSelectedValue()
                System.out.println("else called myList.getSelectedValue() ="+myList.getSelectedValue());
            }
        }
    };

    private ListTest()
    {
        int noRows = 25;
        Object[] listData = new String[noRows];
        for(int i =0; i < noRows; i++)
            listData[i]= "Oi "+i;
        this.myList = new JList(listData);
        this.myScrollPane = new JScrollPane(myList);
        myList.addListSelectionListener(lSL);
        add(myScrollPane);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {               
                ListTest p = new ListTest();
                JPanel contentPane = new JPanel();
                contentPane.add(p);
                JFrame f = new JFrame();
                f.setContentPane(contentPane);
                f.setSize(800, 600);
                f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                f.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Hope that even if it doesn't solve your problem it at least will be helpful in building an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) for us.